# apply all.equal to several objects

Tags: r

I am trying to apply all.equal to several objects at the same time.

my initial code is the following:

```
all.equal(1,1.01, tolerance = 1e-1)
```

This is one way of doing it:

```
objs <- mget(c(1,1.01,1.02))
outer(objs, objs, Vectorize(all.equal))
```

but I cannot figure out how to include the tolerance statement.

Any thoughts?

Comment: i get an error when running your `mget` line. I'm not sure what you are trying to do but maybe it is this?: `sapply(x, FUN=function(x) { all.equal(1,x,tolerance=1e-1)})` where `x = c(1,1.01,1.02)`

Comment: maybe this --> `outer(objs, objs, FUN=function(a,b,toler){ mapply(function(x,y){all.equal(x,y,toler)},a,b) },toler=1e-1)`

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
vec = c(1,1.01,1.02)
all(abs(diff(vec)) <= 0.01 + .Machine$double.eps)
```